# Folland's real analysis, proof of Theorem 3.22

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

When comprehending theorem 3.22, I am stuck in the last step, as highlighted in red:

[image]
[image]

May I ask how we can obtain $m(V_{\epsilon}) \leq 3^n k\epsilon$?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Since $c<m\left(V_{\varepsilon}\right)$ is arbitrary.

Comment: @ling Thanks a lot! Sorry for my lame math background but I'm honestly not aware of why $c<m(V_{\epsilon})$ and $c<3^nk\epsilon$ imply $m(V_{\epsilon}) \leq 3^nk\epsilon$. Could you provide more hints?

Comment: If not, we have $m\left(V_{\varepsilon}\right)>3^nk\varepsilon$. Then we choose $c=\frac{m\left(V_{\varepsilon}\right)+3^nk\varepsilon}{2}$, which satisfies $c<m\left(V_{\varepsilon}\right)$ but $c>3^nk\varepsilon$, contradiction.

Comment: @ling I got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it is better to understand it in the language of supremum.

Put $E=\{c:c<m(V_\varepsilon)\}$, then $\sup E=m(V_\varepsilon)$. Since $c<3^nk\varepsilon$ for all $c \in E$, it follows that $\sup E=m(V_\varepsilon) \le 3^nk\varepsilon$ because otherwise $m(V_\varepsilon)$ would not be the supremum of $E$, a contradiction.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!