Do singular measures have singular distribution functions?
I know that singular fuctions have singular
(Stieltjes)-measures and I am trying to prove the converse:

So consider a positive Borel measure $\mu$ on $\left[0,2\pi\right)$ and its distribution function
$$
\operatorname{F}_{\mu}\left(x\right):= \mu([0,x)]
$$
Suppose $\mu$ is singular with respect to the Lebesgue-measure, restricted to
$[0,2\pi)$, i.e. there is a Borel-set
$A \subset \left[0,2\pi\right)$ of
Lebesgue-measure zero, s.th.
$$
\mu\left(\left(0,2\pi\right] \setminus A\right) = 0
$$
How do I prove that $\operatorname{F}_{\mu}$ is a singular function, i.e. a.e.
differentiable with
$$
\operatorname{F}'\left(x\right) = 0
$$
I tried to compute the differential quotient
for $x\in \left[0,2\pi\right)\setminus A$:
$$
\frac{\mu\left(\left[0,x + h\right)\right)-\mu\left(\left[0,x\right)\right)}{h} = \frac{\mu\left(\left[x,x + h\right)\right)}{h}
$$

How can I prove that this tends to $0$ as
$h \to 0$ ?.




$F_\mu$ is continuous if and only if no singleton has positive probability. Since discrete distributions are singular with respect to Lebesgue measure, the conjecture seems to be wrong.

I think you are right. Would it work if we did not require F to be continuous? I edited the question

Maybe. I don't know.

I don’t know about the result you want to prove, but the current argument is definitely not going to work. For example, fix an irrational $x \in [0, 2\pi)$ and let ${q_n}$ be a sequence of rationals in $[0, 2\pi)$ s.t. $0 < q_n-x < 2^{-2n}$. Then let $\mu = \sum_n 2^{-n}\delta_{q_n}$. $\mu$ is singular and you can choose $A = {q_n}$. But $\frac{\mu([x,x+h))}{h} > 2^n$ when $h = 2^{-2n}$, so $F$ is not differentiable at $x$.

Yes, the result is true. Note that
$$
\frac{F_\mu(x+h)-F_\mu(x)}{h}=\frac{\mu\left([0,x + h)\right)-\mu\left([0,x\right))}{h} = \frac{\mu\left([x,x + h)\right)}{m([x,x + h))}
$$
where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure. Then, using Folland's Theorem 3.22, we have that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\mu\left([x,x + h)\right)}{m([x,x + h))} =0$ for $m$-almost every $x$ (see, for instance, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731321/follands-real-analysis-proof-of-theorem-3-22 ).
